# Two animation, both forwards

Tags: javascript, css

I have a Div with the id of center. I set the opacity of the Div to 0 in CSS file. when the window loads, I give the Div an animation:
    document.getElementById('center').style.animation = "UP 1s forwards";
if the user click a button, I change the animation to:
    document.getElementById('center').style.animation = "DOWN 1s forwards";
Problem: the second animation doesn't show up, the Div suddenly disappear.

Comment: The UP animation is like this:`0% {
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); /* Safari */
  transform: scale(0.5,0.5); /* Standard syntax */
  opacity: 0;
  top: 400px;}
 
 50% {
  -ms-transform: scale(1,1); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1,1); /* Standard syntax */
  opacity: 1px;
  top: -10px;
 }
 
 100%{ top: 0px; opacity: 1;}
}`

Comment: I don't know how to make the comment looks better by breaking the line. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A example fiddle or some more code might help. Lot of things could be wrong.

- Your keyframes for the down animation might be starting with `opacity 0;`
- You need to set some position property in CSS to use top/right/bottom/left properties. Check that.
- There might be something wrong with the JS on click.

Just some things I can think of.

It feels like a toast animation by what you described. Here's a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/thelessergeek/rj7a06hm/

Hopefully you were looking for that. My JS might be a little sad. Work it out as you see fit. Thanks!